# Relative distance, chernoff bound.

Tags: probability

I'm looking over this link: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jfc/cs174/lecs/lec10/lec10.pdf bottom of page 2

Where it says that $\delta = \bigl(1 - \frac{2m}{n} \bigl)$ is the relative distance between the expected value and m.

The expected value is stated as $\frac{n}{2}$ and assume that $m < \frac{n}{2} $

I'm not seeing why delta is what it is, why isn't the relative distance simply $\frac{n}{2} - m$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is about the terminology:
The "absolute" distance is $\frac{n}{2}-m$, but the "relative" distance is obtained by dividing that by $\mu=n/2$. [This is analogous to making an error when measuring an object to be $11$ centimeters long when it is actually $10$ centimeters: the absolute error is $11-10=1$, while the relative error is $1/10$.] In any case, they are just defining $\delta$ in that way, so don't worry about the terminology.

If your question is about why this particular choice of $\delta$ works:
Note that in the Chernoff bound, you're going to multiply $\delta$ by $\mu$ anyway, so what you attain is the absolute distance.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I noticed that dividing by n/2 worked, but wasn't sure why that would be done. Thank you on both fronts.